# (Jquery) Slider - flechas no toman en cuenta en que imagen esta

Tags: jquery, slider

Estoy intentando crear un slider con jquery, empece creando las flechas de hacia atras y hacia delante y funcionaban bien, luego quise crear los botones de abajo para que el usuario pueda dar click e irse a la imagen que quiere, y funcionan bien, pero mi problema esta que cuando le doy a algún boton de abajo y luego quiero usar las flechas, este no sabe en que imagen esta y no funciona, y lo mismo pasa si uso las flechas y luego quiero darle a algún boton de abajo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
slider(500);
function slider(velocidad){

 var x=1;
 var numImg= $(".grande img").length;
 var ultimoMargin= -(numImg-1)*1000+"px";

$(".grande").css("width", numImg * 1000 + "px");

$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".grande").animate({"margin-left":"+=-1000"},velocidad);
    x++;

    if(x == numImg){
        $(".grande").animate({"margin-left":"0px"},0);
        x = 1;
    }

});

$(".prev").click(function(){

    if(x == 1){
        $(".grande").animate({"margin-left": ultimoMargin},0);
        x = numImg;
    }

    $(".grande").animate({"margin-left":"+=1000"},velocidad);
    x--;
});

$(".boton").click(function(){
     paginationPos = $(this).index() + 1;
            console.log(paginationPos);


            $("img").hide();
            $("img:nth-child("+ paginationPos +")").fadeIn();

        });
    }
});
```

Codigo con el html y css https://codepen.io/Aaronr/pen/mBxPXV

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar utilizando el data en el HTML dándole un valor numérico.

JS:

```
$(".boton").click(function(){

    var number = $(this).data("number");
    var calcx = number * 1000;

    $(".grande").animate({marginLeft : "-" + calcx});

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="botones">
    <span data-number="0" class="boton"></span>
    <span data-number="1" class="boton"></span>
    <span data-number="2" class="boton"></span>
    <span data-number="3" class="boton"></span>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLMgVV

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, he aplicado los cambios que me recomiendas pero no termina de funcionar :( si te fijas, reconoce en que imagen esta, pero ahora cuando le doy a uno de los botones de abajo, y  luego uso las flecha derecha y llego hasta la imagen final, donde debería volver a la primera imagen, o en su defecto, voy a la primera imagen y le doy a la flecha izquierda, donde debería ir hasta la ultima, lo que hace es quedarse la imagen en negro